# Php datetime fatal error in php 5.1.1

Tags: php, datetime, fatal-error

Is there any way to use datetime function in `php 5.1.1`.

I'm getting following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'DateTime' not found and i have to convert date into ISO8601 format.
```

If I upgrade my php version, will effect my current php code?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps it's time to upgrade to a version of PHP that wasn't EOL more than a decade ago

Comment: DateTime wasn't introduced until PHP 5.2 ... As for whether upgrading to a newer version of PHP will introduce any issues it is really impossible to tell without an indepth look at all your source code. I would suggest looking through the migration docs http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/migration56.php

Answer (score 0):

Put a backslash in front of the class name to indicate it is in the global namespace:

```
$time = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
```

Comment: If it's PHP 5.1.1, then namespacing doesn't exist in PHP; it wasn't introduced until version 5.3